# Regular expression to trim a string

Tags: regex, string, c#-4.0

In my application, i am trying to get the name of a file, from a string retrieved from a 'content-header' tag from a server. The filename looks like `\"uploads/2014/03/filename.zip\"` (quotations included in value).

I have tried using `Path.GetFileName(string);` to get just the file name but it throws an exception stating that there are illegal characters in the path.

What should i use to get just `filename.zip` returned? is a regex the best way to trim this string off or is there a better one?

the `\"uploads/2014/03/` part will always be the same length. The `filename.zip` can be any filename and extension, im just using that as an example. But the numbers may vary. It sounds like a job for a regex to me, but i have no idea how to use regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
var inputString = @"\""uploads/2014/03/filename.zip\""";

var result = inputString.Trim('\\', '"').Split('/')[3];
```

This should work if the format is always like `\"uploads/someNumber/someOtherNumber/filename\"`.In order to make it more safe you might want to use [`Enumerable.Last`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358775%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method after `Split`:

```
var result = inputString.Trim('\\', '"').Split('/').Last();
```